# Array count that does not odr-use?

Tags: c++

There are several good reasons to prefer

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t ARRAY_COUNT_FUNC(T (&arr)[N]) { return N; }
```

rather than

```
#define ARRAY_COUNT_MACRO(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr))
```

One important difference is that when a pointer (not an array) is passed to `ARRAY_COUNT_MACRO`, it silently returns an unhelpful answer, but passing the same argument to `ARRAY_COUNT_FUNC` will cause a compiler error pointing out the mistake.

But the macro does have one advantage: its argument is unevaluated.

```
#include <utility>
struct S {
    int member_array[5];
};

// OK:
std::size_t count1 = ARRAY_COUNT_MACRO(std::declval<S&>().member_array);

// ERROR: std::declval is odr-used!
std::size_t count2 = ARRAY_COUNT_FUNC(std::declval<S&>().member_array);
```

Is there another approach with the benefits of both together?  I. e., something that causes a compile error if the argument is not an array, and does not odr-use its argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shamelessly ripped off from the Chromium project, as described [here](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0074/).

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t ARRAY_COUNT_FUNC(T (&arr)[N]) { return N; }

#define ARRAY_COUNT_MACRO(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr))

// Template for typesafey goodness.
template <typename T, size_t N>
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];
// sizeof to avoid actually calling the function.
#define arraysize(array) (sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(array)))

struct S {
    int member_array[5];
};

int main()
{

    // OK:
    std::size_t count1 = ARRAY_COUNT_MACRO(std::declval<S&>().member_array);

    // ERROR: std::declval is odr-used!
    //std::size_t count2 = ARRAY_COUNT_FUNC(std::declval<S&>().member_array);

    // OK:
    std::size_t count2 = arraysize(std::declval<S&>().member_array);

    // ERROR:
    // int * p;
    // std::size_t count3 = arraysize(p);
}
```

Comment: Lord only knows how long ago the idea was first hatched, but [Microsoft uses essentially the same algorithm](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx) for their `_countof(ar)` macro, and has since at least '04. Chance are they probably *unshamelessly* ripped it off from someone else.

Answer (score 2):

... And then I remembered `<type_traits>` has a `std::is_array` template.  Another solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr auto ArrayCountImpl(std::nullptr_t)
    -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_array<typename
                                   std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value,
                               std::size_t>::type
{ return std::extent<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value; }

template<typename T>
std::size_t ArrayCountImpl(...)
{ static_assert(!std::is_same<T,T>::value,
                "Argument type is not an array"); }

#define ARRAY_COUNT_MACRO_2(arr) (ArrayCountImpl<decltype(arr)>(nullptr))
```