# calculate number of elements from a fixed array (similar to sizeof)

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof, typeof

I'm developing a library in C++ in order to give to developers an help to some tasks.
Usually, in order to calculate the size of an array of integer (for example) in a dynamic way (without use #define SIZE or static int SIZE), I do sizeof(v) / sizeof(int). I'm trying to write a piece of code that can do for me that stuff automatically and I decided to call if lengthof.
The code is here:

```
template <class T> int _typesize(T*) { return sizeof(T); }
#define lengthof(x) (sizeof(x) / _typesize(&x))
```

I use the template to get the type of the array, then I return its size in bytes. In GCC I know that it's possible to use typeof, so I can replace _typesize(&x) with sizeof(typeof(x)), but it's not possible on MSVC. _typesize is a compatible way, but I think that it can be expensive because it passes the pointer as copy. There is an elegant way to do this?

Comment: `std::vector` or `std::array`

Comment: Use the `ArraySizeHelper` function and `arraysize` macro from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14713274/459640

Comment: Passing a pointer by copy is _hardly_ an expensive operation...

Comment: For local variables that doesn't uses much memory I usually uses C-style arrays (due to stack vs heap etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for macros for this task.  If you have a conforming compiler

```
template<class T, size_t len>
constexpr size_t lengthof(T(&)[len]) {return len;}
//the parameter is an unnamed reference to a `T[len]`, 
//where `T` is deduced as the element type of the array
//and len is deduced as the length of the array.
//similar to `T(*)[len]` in C, except you can pass the array
//directly, instead of passing a pointer to it.
//added benefit that if you pass a `T*` to it, it produces a compiler error.
```

Or if you're using Visual Studio which is not yet conforming...

```
template<class T, size_t len>
std::integral_constant<size_t, len> lengthof(T(&)[len]) {return {};}
//VC++ doesn't have constexpr, so we have to use `std::integral_constant` instead :(
//but how it works is 100% identical
```

If you want a more portable way, macros still work best:

```
#define lengthof(arr) sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])
//doesn't respect namespaces, evaluates arguments multiple times
//and if you pass a `T*` to it, it evaluates to `1` depending on context.
```

But to reiterate my comment, I would consider all of this bad code.  Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: Could you give some small explanation to a C programmer now on C++ on what does `T(&)[len]`?

Comment: @TheMask: A reference to an array of length `len` and element type `T`. The similar pointer type, `T(*)[len]`, is the same as in C.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Thanks. From where come from `len` argument in this `template`? is this some type of overloading?

Comment: @TheMask: If you have a `char array[3]`, then `array` is of type `char[3]`.  When you call `lengthof(array)`, the C++ compiler knows that the parameter is `char(&)[3]`, so deduces that `T` must be `char` and `len` must be `3`.  Then the function returns `len`, which is `3`.  For this example, it's 100% equivalent to `constexpr size_t lengthof( char(&)[3]) {return 3;}`.  The `constexpr` means it's executed at compile time (ish), so there's no runtime overhead at all.

Comment: I like the T(&)[n] solution, thank you! Oh, honestly I forgot that I can use also sizeof(v[0]) :P that's a good solution for ANSI C code.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you would use: `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])` which doesn't rely on any extensions.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical C++ way to get the length of an array is `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`. Whether you want to hide that by packing it into a macro is another debate entirely.

As a side note, if your `_typesize` is in the global namespace then that name is reserved for the implementation and illegal to use. In a namespace it's technically legal but generally speaking you can avoid reserved name problems by just avoiding leading underscores entirely.